# Iterate a large .xz file line by line in python

Tags: python, lzma, xz

I have a large .xz file (few gigabytes). It's full of plain text. I want to process the text to create custom dataset. I want to read it line by line because it is too big. Anyone have an idea how to do it ?

I already tried this
[How to open and read LZMA file in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653883/how-to-open-and-read-lzma-file-in-memory) but it's not working.

EDIT:
i got this error 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

on the line `for line in uncompressed:` from the link

EDIT2: My code (using python 3.5)

```
with open(filename) as compressed:
    with lzma.LZMAFile(compressed) as uncompressed:
        for line in uncompressed:
            print(line)
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Questions seeking help debugging should include a [mcve]

Comment: i ll edit the question

Comment: Can we see the code that you are using not just the error message? And what version of Python are you using?

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was faced to the same question some weeks ago. This snippet worked for me:

```
import lzma
with lzma.open('filename.xz', mode='rt') as file:
    for line in file:
       print(line)
```

This assumes that the text data in the compressed file was encoded in **utf-8** (which was the case for my data). There is an `encoding` argument in function `lzma.open()` which allows you to set another encoding if needed

EDIT (after you own edit): try to force `encoding='utf-8'` in `lmza.open()`

Comment: Thx man! I used your code with the encoding parameter and it worked. :)